# Java GUI application

Tags: java, swing, jframe, event-dispatch-thread, thread-sleep

I am working on a Java graphical interface (Swing , AWT) . The data entry in my application is supposed to be done via a `JFrame`. In fact I have 10 entities that necessitate 10 `JFrame`s. I used a `for` loop but `JFrame`s don't seem to wait until data entry.

I used `Thread.sleep()` but in vain. Any help?

Here is some of my code:

```
for (int i=0; i < VMnumber; i++) // VMnumber : number of virtual machines to instantiate
{
    mips=0;
    frame=new VMcaracteristics(); // VMcaracteristics is a JFrame to enter VMs caracteristics
    frame.setVisible(true);
    while (!VMcaracteristicsFlag) // Current frame is still open
    {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } // create a VM correspondent to the current frame
    vm = new Vm(vmid, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new CloudletSchedulerTimeShared());
    vmlist.add(vm);
}
```

Comment: Can we get a bit of the code? Perhaps the initialization and the part involving the loops?

Comment: What did you try? Any code example?

Comment: Are you looking for a "submit" button, or something that detects any change to a configuration as it happens? I don't think that this is answerable right now without more code/details as to what exactly you want to happen, and what is currently happening.

Comment: I would use just one JFrame and either have the entry fields for all the data present on the one GUI view (one JPanel), or use CardLayout to swap JPanel views after each section of data entry has been complete. This is a lot less jarring than throwing bunches of windows at the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html).

```
String data = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    null, //parent window
    "Hi! Enter some data, please:", //text
    "Input", //title
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE //icon?
);
```

Explore the documentation to find the best method for your needs.

**Edit:** JOptionPane actually blocks, so you can loop:

```
String[] data = new String[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data[i] = JOptionPane.showXXX(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your underlying question (in my mind) is not so much how to display 10 windows, one after the other, but rather, how to get multiple bits of information from the user in an easy and straightforward way, both for you the coder and the user. If you are dead set about throwing a bunch of windows at the user, then yes, use J4v4's solution of multiple JOptionPanes (1+ to his answer), or modal JDialogs (which JOptionPane is in fact one variant of). If you want a better user experience, though consider showing the user all input fields, perhaps in a multi-row JTable or in several JPanels held in a GridLayout container held in a JScrollPane. If you absolutely need to display 10 views sequentially, consider using one CardLayout using JPanel that then displays 10 view "card" JPanels sequentially.

Also, you never want to call `Thread.sleep(...)` or `while (true)` on the Swing event thread as this will block this important thread, one that is needed for all Swing drawing and user interaction, and will effectively put your whole application to sleep.